# Get continuous data from UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

How can I tap into the momentary value of a currently spinning `UIPickerView`? (`UISlider` has a "continuous" mode, but `UIPickerView` hasn’t.)

Any idea for a workaround? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @AntonioMG is right. There isn't a way to get around this **unless** you made a custom picker or look around for a 3rd-party component. You might want to take a look at [cocoacontrols.com](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) if you really need this functionality.

Comment: This **is** possible - see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

The delegate for the UIPickerView only let you get the selected one:

```
– pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:
```

You won't get an event when the picker is spinning, for example like the one you could get in a UIScrollView when is scrolling.

Im afraid there's no direct way of getting it

Answer (score 0):

To get continuous data from a `UIPickerView`, you just need to start a timer and call the picker's `selectedRow(inComponent:)` function.

Something like this…

```
class TextSettingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet fileprivate weak var picker: UIPickerView!

    weak var timer: Timer?

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [unowned self] timer in
            let row = self.picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            print("selectedRow: \(row)")
        }

        // You need to add the timer to UITrackingRunLoopMode so it fires while scrolling the picker
        let runLoop = RunLoop.current
        runLoop.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
        runLoop.add(timer, forMode: .UITrackingRunLoopMode)

        self.timer = timer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a CADisplayLink

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;

self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];

- (void) handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *) displayLink
{
    NSLog(@"%s %ld", __func__, [self selectedRowInComponent:0]);
}
```